# MySql localhost vs Amazon RDS instance Performance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running Django Rest API on an AWS ec2-server. Right now the Api's are using MySql localhost database. Should I shift my database from `MySql localhost` to `Amazon RDS instance`?

As per what I Know for remote servers would take a little extra time to transmit the request and shared resources. Would this little extra time be worth migrating my database from `MySql localhost` to `Amazon RDS instance`?

I read this answer but it didn't helped me much.
[MySql localhost vs Amazon RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371916/mysql-localhost-vs-amazon-rds-instance)

> An answer with all possible Pros and Cons will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Pros for local MySQL**

- Slightly faster, because of proximity to the application

**Cons for local MySQL**

- Not Easily Scalable
- If you want to use autoscaling for your application load and traffic then you might have nightmares, because as you scale you will have even the MySQL servers running on each new node.

**Pros for RDS**

- You don't have to worry about installing and maintaining MySQL server
- You don't have to worry about scaling
- You don't have to worry about load balancing
- You don't have to worry about EC2 upgrades and patching
- You don't have to worry about failure recovery because when you provision a Multi-AZ DB Instance, Amazon RDS synchronously replicates the data to a standby instance in a different Availability Zone (AZ)List item

**Cons for RDS**

- Slightly slower due to network latency

Answer (score 0):

It depends how database intensive your application is.

See [this benchmark](https://medium.com/linux-academy/https-medium-com-claude-ducharme-aws-services-performance-benchmark-bbcf4e44c43) The local database blew RDS out of the water on query latency with low load.

The answer is probably use both? Use both a local Redis/MySQL for quick queries and an off server RDS for long queries over large data sets where paying the additional network latency makes sense.

Also think about using SQLite on S3. If you can easily shard your data, and most queries are read intensive it could be a lot cheaper, especially with something like Redis on the server to cache frequent queries.

If you want to really eek out performance per $$, you can use a lot of [Pang's tricks](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/rtd/15942/) by having a hierarchy of SQLite files.